# Nativescript Angular - Property 'SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY' does not exist on type 'typeof View'

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, typescript-typings, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to set my uiVisibility on Android to sticky and immersive like this:

```
    const View = android.view.View;
    const window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
    const decorView = window.getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-bitwise
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

But everytime i build im getting an ERROR message in my terminal, something like this

```
ERROR in src/app/common/services/ui.service.ts:25:18 - error TS2339: Property 'SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY' does not exist on type 'typeof View'.

25             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Now, I manage to get around this by adding a constant value to my /node_modules/@nativescript/types-android/lib/android/android-platform-17.d.ts file and after that I get no errors. Althought this works, im not fond of meddling with my files in node_modules, and I'm sure I'm not intended to do it and also everytime I tns clean && npm install I get the error back again. The thing is, I don't get why the reference is to to the platform-17 file, since my target sdk version is 23, there's no point in referncing this file.

I'm using Nativesript 7 with Angular 10 for my project and my references.d.ts file looks liek this:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/types/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/types/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/types/android.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/core/global-types.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide specific platform types

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/types-android/lib/android-23.d.ts" />
```